# error making a copy of google app script

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-script

I'm trying to duplicate a Google app script file in Google drive that I own, but it gives me this error `Limit Exceeded: Create.` This is when I'm in the file and I use `File` --> `Make a copy...`

When I try to just right click and `Make a copy` it says `Error creating "xxx"`.

Other files, such as Google sheets, seem to be duplicating fine.

EDIT: This morning it is copying fine. Not sure what happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message implies that there is a limit for the creation of new files and it was exceeded.

Google has limits for several actions in their products in order to prevent abuses. Once exceeded they could be blocked from few minutes to 24 hrs or even could cause the account suspension.

The limits could vary from time to time and could be different for each kind of Google accounts.

**References**

- [Limits on sharing - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494827?hl=en)
- [File sizes -  Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en)
- [Quotas for Google Services - Apps Script Guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)